# Problemas con el enrutamiento react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation

no se si alguien me puede indicar o guiar un poco, estoy intentando cargar en un pagina un componente con una navegacion, inicialmente trabaja bien como lo podemos ver aqui [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero al refrescar la pagina se me pierde la navegacion asi, es como si se perdiera la referencia al componente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el componente que carga el routing

```js
import React from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
import Sidebar from './Sidebar'
import AreaPersonal from './AreaPersonal';
import Calificaciones from './Calificaciones';

const Tablero = () => {
    return ( 
        <Router>        
            <div className="page-wrapper chiller-theme toggled"
                <Sidebar/>
                {/* <!-- sidebar-wrapper  --> */}
                <main className="page-content">
                    <div className="container-fluid prueba">
                        <h2>Pro Sidebar</h2>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route path="/personal" component={AreaPersonal}></Route>    
                            <Route path="/calificaciones" component={Calificaciones}></Route>     
                        </Switch>    
                    </div>
                </main>
                {/* <!-- page-content" --> */}
            </div>
      </Router>
    );
}
export default Tablero;
```

Sidebar es un componente que maneja todo el menu de navegación, gracias de antemano si alguien me puede guiar en el manejo de react-router-dom.

Comment: Muestra algún mensaje por consola cuando accedes directamente y no se muestra?

Comment: no aparentemente trabaja bien pero me sale ese error, quite lo que pasa es que tenia dos navegaciones quite una y funciono, pero solo me deja trabajar con una y yo necesitaba las dos navegaciones, sabes deopronto como puedo anidar navegaciones en react